# Makefile not expanding glob because of zsh?

Tags: makefile, zsh

I have a line in my Makefile that's about something like that:

`prog /something/f.{one,two,three}`

but running the make file I get from prog that

`/something/f.{one,two,three}` does not exist. Which leads me to believe that make
is not expanding the glob. Normally this would work for me in Bash but I'm running zshell now so I think that's the problem. Anyone know how to specify that pattern portably?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, note that make _always_ runs /bin/sh when it invokes a shell.  It doesn't run whatever shell the user happens to prefer (imagine what a portability disaster that would be!)  Curly-brace expansion is not part of the POSIX standard for sh, so /bin/sh often doesn't support it.

Comment: You could set `SHELL` to `/bin/zsh` in your Makefile, but that leads to the portability disaster mentioned by @MadScientist (if someone using your Makefile doesn't have `/bin/zsh`, the Makefile won't work for them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to what [ThePosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67455/theposey) suggested would be making use of [`addprefix`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions):

```
FILE_SUFFIXES := one two three
FILE_BASE := /something/f

FILES := $(addprefix $(FILE_BASE).,$(FILE_SUFFIXES))

my_rule:
    prog $(FILES)
```

Comment: I think you meant `FILE_SUFFIXES := one two three`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be shell expanded? Make can do something similar for you. This is just one way to do it:

```
EXPANDED_POSTFIX := one two three
BASE_FILE := f.

PROG_FILE_LIST := $(foreach post,${EXPANDED_POSTFIX},${BASE_FILE}${post})

exec_prog:
    prog ${PROG_FILE_LIST}
```